# Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx0m

Tags: jenkins, xvfb, okd

I am getting the following text while running xvfb build config on OKD & which leads to pod termination

```
exec java -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Xmx0m -cp /home/jenkins/remoting.jar hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main -headless -url http://192.168.247.189:80/ -tunnel 192.168.198.249:50000 09d85a0ed4e8b67a0e8bc448cba7c0e5aea962f34b782dcf22597494e8e0e921 xvfb-mlhmf
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx0m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
couldn't find "-Xmx0m" in either of yaml( buildconfig & Deploymentconfig)
```

I'm trying to run Jenkins and I am facing an xvfb issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem when compiling projects in my jenkins instance deployed in OKD after updating it to version **4.12**. It is strange because I'm using exactly the same docker images to compile my maven/nodejs projects.

However I have solved it by passing **JAVA_MAX_HEAP_PARAM** as environment variable to my compilation pods.

To do so, go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure Clouds" -> "Pod Templates" -> "Pod Template Details..." -> "Environment Variable":

[image]

If you rather see the changes in xml, this is how it should look like after changes are made:

```
          <envVars>
            <org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.model.KeyValueEnvVar>
              <key>JAVA_MAX_HEAP_PARAM</key>
              <value>-Xmx512m</value>
            </org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.model.KeyValueEnvVar>
          </envVars>
```